# PCA - Removing variables with high loadings in several factors

Tags: pca, spss, references

I have variables with factor loadings similar to each other (PCA - Varimax). For example 0.536 and 0.602 etc. Please see the example: `Self direction_10`.
I have read that I can remove such variables. In my case I have done so and I got much clearer factors.

Is there any reliable reference to support this decision?

I have read that others have done it - but they hardly reference their work to support this!

As a side note for example, I am keeping `Achievement_7` even as Component 2 has a reasonably higher load compared to .416.

[image]

Comment: Can you post an example where someone did this? I can't think of any reason why this would make sense.

Comment: @JeffreyGirard I have included an example.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood. You don't mean that item A and item B have similar loadings on Factor 1. You mean that item A loads similarly on both Factor 1 and Factor 2.

Comment: That's correct. Apologies

Comment: You can do anything you want, of course.  But to determine whether it makes sense or can be useful to remove variables with comparable loadings on the factors, please tell us the objectives of your analysis and what you hope such removals will accomplish.